# Android: Ask user to either enable wifi or quit app

Tags: android, wifi, modal-dialog, quit

I'm developing a simple app that requires network connectivity to function. When the app starts, and if there is no wi-fi connection, I want to display a modal dialog to the user with two options: 
1) Enable wifi or 2) Quit the application.

The problem is that I can't find an android method that can be called to close the application if the 'close app' button is clicked.

Is there such a method that I haven't found yet? Or is there some better way to handle this entire use case?

Comment: The method for close app?, is it `finish()`?

Answer (score 3):

To check the **Internet Connection** use this code:

```
private boolean haveNetworkConnection() {
          final ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService (Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
             if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable() &&    conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
                   return true;
             } else {
                   System.out.println("Internet Connection Not Present");
                 return false;
             }
}
```

And to **Quit Application** on Button click use this code :

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Try it..

Answer (score 1):

I had a simillar code for checking wifi speed . Please see whether this helps or not :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TextView text= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TV);

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager =(ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo info = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (info == null ||
            !connectivityManager.getBackgroundDataSetting()) {
        // No Network detected
        findViewById(R.id.quit).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.quit).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();
            }
        });
        //return;
    }else {
        int netType = info.getType();
        int netSubtype = info.getSubtype();
        if (netType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
            //WIFI DETECTED
            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();

            int linkSpeed = wifiInfo.getLinkSpeed(); //measured using WifiInfo.LINK_SPEED_UNITS
            text.setText("Connection is wifi and the speed is "+Integer.toString(linkSpeed));


        } else if (netType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE
                && netSubtype >2) {
            text.setText("connection is 3g");  
        } else {
            text.setText("connection is 2g");

        }


    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using finish() to close the first activity in the app. This closes the app. (I think)

Answer (score 0):

You should think about the Quit Opinion,

here is an good Answer about Quiting an App [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon/2034238#2034238)

You can say that no WiFi is present.

And if you just make an **AlerDialog** like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Hint"
                        .setMessage("No WiFi!"
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();
```

Or a **Toast** like:

```
Toast.makeText(yourActivity.this, "No WiFi!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

If you whant to check for an **connection**, you can use this snippet:

```
public boolean isOnline() {
        // check if an internet connection is present
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (!(netInfo != null && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable() && cm
                .getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected())) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I understood that your problem is closing the application, right ? Did you try `finish();` ?