# Return Value in ConnectivityManager and/or NetworkInfo in ADT - Android

Tags: android, connectivity, eclipse-adt

When I use the below code to show my connection state, "if" condition always returns "true", unless I put  "netinfo" equal "null".

Where is the problem?

```
public boolean isConnectedToInternet()
{   
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if ( netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting())
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "On",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.i("NewsList", "Internet Connection found.");
            return true;
        }

    Toast.makeText(this, "Off",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Check this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18525924/android-ask-user-to-either-enable-wifi-or-quit-app/18526358#18526358

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

**DetectConnection.class:**

```
public class DetectConnection {
    /*
     * Checking internet connection
     */
    public static boolean checkInternetConnection(Context context) {

        ConnectivityManager con_manager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        if (con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                && con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                && con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Check internet from another activity:

```
if (DetectConnection.checkInternetConnection(this)) {
        //do something
}
```

Comment: thanx , but it return "true" still